# Can't get any entity associated to a tree entity

Tags: symfony, tree, nested, associations

I'm working on an e-learning application and I have to categorize courses. So my Section entity is one of Tree extension. In order to retrieve all courses of a section, I made the following assoication:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Svi\FormationBundle\Entity\Course", mappedBy="section")
 */
private $courses;
```

The problem is that when I try get courses in twig doing this `{% if section.courses|length > 0 %}`, I receive this error message

```
Key "courses" for array with keys "id, titre, sommaire, slug, deactivated, lft, lvl, rgt, root, __children" does not exist in SviFormationBundle:Formation:see_courses.html.twig at line 22.
```

I made a dump on the section object and it displayed all attributes except ones of OneToMany and ManyToOne associations. Any help please? Isn't it possible to associate other entities to a Tree entity? If so how to make a nested classification in Symfony? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have to explicitely add the 'join' or 'leftJoin' to the 'Course' entity.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Here's my code:  `$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('node')
            ->innerJoin('node.formation', 'f', 'WITH', 'f.slug = :slug')
            ->leftJoin('node.courss', 'c')
            ->orderBy('node.root, node.lft', 'ASC')
            ->setParameters(array('slug' => $slug))
            ->getQuery()
        ;`  Anyway, I got the error.